# How to check OPA Rego file is correct or not

Tags: go, base64, opa, rego

I have created one `sample.rego` file and I encoded in base64.
so is there any way in **`Golang`** Library that validate rego base64 encoded value is correct or not.

1. Sample.rego file:

   ```
   package policy.authz

   default allow = false
   allow {
     input.policy == "abcd"
   }
   ```
2. Base64 encoded value is :

   cGFja2FnZSBwb2xpY3kuYXV0aHoKCiMgbG9naWMgdGhhdCBpbXBsZW1lbnRzIHBvbGljeS4KZGVmYXVsdCBhbGxvdyA9IGZhbHNlCmFsbG93IHsKICBpbnB1dC5wb2xpY3kgPT0gImFiY2QiCn0=

**Now I have to validate with the help of GoLang Library that file we encoded is valid.**

Now If I changed Sample.rego file to :

```
package policy.authz
default allow = false
allow {
  wrong dummy data
  input.policy == "abcd"
}
```

- Base64 encoded value is :

> cGFja2FnZSBwb2xpY3kuYXV0aHoKZGVmYXVsdCBhbGxvdyA9IGZhbHNlCmFsbG93IHsKICB3cm9uZyBkdW1teSBkYXRhCiAgaW5wdXQucG9saWN5ID09ICJhYmNkIgp9

**Now I have to validate with the help of GoLang Library that file we encoded is not valid.**

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way in Golang Library that validate rego base64 encoded value is correct or not.

You have to decode it, if it fails it's not base64 or not encoded correctly.

Here you have an example.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func IsBase64(s string) bool {
    _, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(s)
    return err == nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(IsBase64(`Invalid string`))
    fmt.Println(IsBase64(`VmFsaWQgc3RyaW5nCg==`))
}
```

Comment: Hi @Wolfgang That will not help because I have to validate file that is written in correct way. If I changed my file                                                                              
package policy.authz

default allow = false
allow { Wrong Input 
  input.policy == "abcd"
} .. So this rego file it's not valid

Answer (score 0):

```
       import "github.com/open-policy-agent/opa/ast"

        modules := map[string]*ast.Module{}
        compiler := ast.NewCompiler()
        modules["policyModule"], err = ast.ParseModule("policyModule", string(policy))
        if err!=nil{
            log.Error(err, "unable to parse the module")
        }
    
        compiler.Compile(modules)
        if compiler.Failed() {
            log.Error(compiler.Errors, "unable to compile the module")
            
        }
```

Comment: The above code is working as expected